# Mailjet templating language(TWIG, PUG syntax) - how to use template variable within inline style prop?

Tags: django-templates, pug, mailjet, templating-engine

I'm trying to customize my e-mail templates using the Mailjet Passport tool. The HTML code generated by Passport Drag and Drop tool, supports templating language that is similiar to Twig.

What I need to achieve is to put variable for inline style property like on the code example below:

```html
  <span
    style="color: {{var: PARTNER_COLOR:"#d2d2d2"}};" // it does not work
   >
    Lorem ipsum {{var:PARTNER_NAME:"Default Partner"}}.mywebstite.de <!-- this work as expected -->
 </span>
```

Interpolating the `{{var:VARIABLE_NAME}}` within inner HTML content or for `src` attribute works as expected, but I'm not able to figure out how to use them with the `style` attribute.
Maybe there is some other solution for dynamically changing color values for css `color`, `background` properties in my e-mail templates?

Docs are very poor to be honest, but here is the reference: [Maijlet Templating Language Docs](https://dev.mailjet.com/email/template-language/)

Comment: What does this question have to do with Pug?

Comment: @sean The syntax is almost identical so I thought solutions from PUG or TWIG can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of days I have finally found and answer.
For anyone looking for this in the future **there can't be any space sign before the curly braces and var declaration** like in the example below:

BAD:

```
<span
    style="color: {{var: PARTNER_COLOR:"#d2d2d2"}};" // it does not work
   >
    Lorem ipsum {{var:PARTNER_NAME:"Default Partner"}}.mywebstite.de <!-- this work as expected -->
</span>
```

GOOD:

```
 <span
    style="color:{{var:PARTNER_COLOR:"#d2d2d2"}};" // THIS WORKS!
   >
    Lorem ipsum {{var:PARTNER_NAME:"Default Partner"}}.mywebstite.de <!-- this work as expected -->
 </span>
```